# Prevent object creation of a public class by user of a jar

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I have a public class whose only public function returns an iterator on objects:

```
public class WikiExtractor implements Iterable<WikiPage>{
...
    public Iterator startExtraction() {
       Thread executor = new Thread(() -> startExtraction_0());
        executor.start();
        return new WikiIterator();
    }
...
}
```

Now the class *WikiPage* is a public class in a different package. How do I prevent user from creating an object of *WikiPage*?  Is putting *WikiPage* in the same package and making it private the only option?

Comment: Off the top off my head - you could make the constructor `private` or `protected` and then use a factory pattern to control who can create it.  Another solution would be to make `WikiPage` an `interface` and use a factory pattern to create the physical implementation ... as a couple of ideas

Comment: You can probably use Java Platform Module System (JPMS)

Comment: Putting `WikiPage` in the same package and making its constructor package-private is going to be by far the simplest option.